# Multiple-readers, single-writer synchronization lock between processes on Windows with WinAPI/C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, synchronization, readerwriterlock

There's a well-known algorithm that employs readers/writer lock synchronization between threads of a single process on a Windows platform using pure WinAPIs/C++:

[Here's an example](http://www.glennslayden.com/code/win32/reader-writer-lock)

In my case I need to do this between several processes, i.e. the writer is in one process, and readers are in other processes. Any idea how to do that?

PS. I need this for an already developed project, so I can't use anything other than C++/MFC or pure WinAPIs. In other words I can't use Boost or the like extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same algorithm but instead of `CriticalSection` you can use [Mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the WinAPI.
If you use the same name for your Mutex objects you can use them in several processes.

Comment: Thank you. Global named mutexes will indeed solve the critical section problem. But my main concern is the 'm_cReaders' counter, since EnterReader()/LeaveReader() will be called from different reader processes. So how do you implement that?

Comment: @ahmd0: Just put your counter in a [shared memory area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Give your event a name and then it should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it. But I've encountered one issue with such approach. If I simply increment or decrement the reader counter like they do in that sample, I can run into a "situation" if one of the reader processes crashes and doesn't decrement its counter. This situation will deadlock my mechanism.